# Can i remap emoticons in hipchat?

Tags: emoticons, remap, hipchat

I am used to other messaging services where (y) is a thumbs up, or affirmative.  I hate having to type (thumbsup) in full or in part and then select the right emoticon.

Yes, this is very much a FWP, but is there a way to remap emoticons in hipchat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently. However it is possible to upload your own emotes and give them specific values like `(y)` for example. Only work around @ this point in time.